# How to download wall posts with FBConnect iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios, fbconnect

I'm trying to download a users wall posts. The FB account i'm getting the posts from is always going to be set to public so I don't think there's any need to log in. I can't seem to find any documentation on the FBConnect iOS SDK so i'm hoping somebody here can help me.

The newest SDK is using

```
- (void)requestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)graphPath
               andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
             andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)delegate;
```

to get data from the user graph. The problem is that I have no idea what the acceptable parameters are or what the graphPath is. I think the graph path is simply the name after www.facebook.com but I'm not sure.

What I would like to do is get the last 20 wall posts made on a public artist page.

Thanks in advance!

Oh also if you know of a good place to get some FBConnect iOS documentation that would be awesome. I know there's a tiny bit on the git hub download page but I would love to see something a little more complete.

UPDATE

I found some decent documentation. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
I also found that if you just want the owner of the pages post you specify /userID/posts rather than /userID/feed.

Comment: I show the dcumentation . is there any demo project available so I can learn more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first parameter is indeed @"userid/feed"
2. the second is empty because feed does not need any parameter so `[NSDictionary dictionary]` will do fine.
3. the third is a reference to a class implementing the FBRequestDelegate protocol.

The protocol is defining two methods :

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
```

pretty straight forward: the result is either an array or a dictionary depending on what you request a feed will typically be a NSArray of post.

Look at the [GraphApi](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) Doc to learn more about graphPath.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, worked great! Do you know what messages come down with the feed? Does this include user comments too? I'm only interested in getting the the messages posted by the owner of the page. Do you know of a way to request the last 10 posts from the owner? I've already added the key "limit" to the dictionary but I seem to be getting all kinds of messages that i'm not interested in. Also do you know if the available params are documented somewhere? Thanks again

Comment: Found the answers to my questions, look for update in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't use `FBConnect`.  simply start up a `NSURLConnection` (in your `viewDidLoad` function perhaps) and parse the Facebook JSON feed in `connectionDidFinishLoading` function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                 [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/feed", @"http://graph.facebook.com/", @"cocacola"]]];
        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [parser objectWithString:json];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [dictionary mutableArrayValueForKey:@"data"];
    int len = [arr count];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        NSDictionary *d = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
        [list addObject:d];
    }
    [json release];
    [parser release];
}
```

where `list` is an `NSMutableArray`, `SBJsonParser` is imported(json-framework for objective-c, see http://json.org), `responseData` is an `NSMutableData`

after this, access `list` to display wall posts:

`NSString *message= [[list objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"message"];`

if you want to grab a user's profile icon, use this:

```
self.profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/picture", @"http://graph.facebook.com/", @"cocacola"]]]];
```

where `profileImage` is a `UIImage` object.

be sure to replace `@"cocacola"` with the appropriate user ID

Comment: Interesting approach. I added the code to my project but arr inside of connectionDidFinishLoading always contains 0 objects. Also, is there a way to limit the number of wall posts that I get? I'm probably only interested in the last 10 or so posts. 

Thanks!

Comment: Stupid mistake, I didn't allocate the responseData object.

Comment: i don't think facebook allows you to limit the results.. read up on the facebook graph api: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Comment: FaceBook Graph API provides parameters to limit the results. Please check following 'limit' and 'offset' parameters.https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?offset=2&limit=3